# "There is insufficient memory. Save the document now." error while opening word 2003 document

Tags: windows-services, ms-office, c#-2.0, office-interop

I have developed one windows service through which I am trying to open an word document. But when service tries to open document, it logs following error `"There is insufficient memory. Save the document now."`
If I run the same program as normal windows application, it works fine but problem comes only when I  try to run the program as windows service.

I tried to google this problem, but there arent many answers about this problem. Is there any way to increase the memory limit for windows service or process? Something like in Java world, where we can specify memory limit while executing java class `java -Xmx800M`. Is there something similar for windows processes?

Does anyone knows how to solve this problem? I am using C#, .net framework 2.0 and office 2003 for development.

Comment: I know this is old, but I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1680214/402706

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that office automation is not recommended by microsoft on server side code.
More information can be found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=257757).

EDIT : 
I found [one more article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311452) regarding office automation in server side code.