# opening powerpoint presentations in ruby via win32ole

Tags: ruby, powerpoint, win32ole

I've got this piece of code that works for Excel.

```
  require 'win32ole'
  excel = WIN32OLE.new('Excel.Application')
  excel.visible = true
  workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open('c:\file.xls');
```

But I have trouble getting the same thing done with for PowerPoint; This piece of code:

```
  require 'win32ole'
  ppt = WIN32OLE.new('Powerpoint.Application')
  ppt.visible = true
  presentation = ppt.Presentations.Open('c:\file.pptx');
```

Generates this error:

```
filename.rb in `method_missing': (in OLE method `Open': ) (WIN32OLERuntimeError)
OLE error code:80004005 in <Unknown>
<No Description>
HRESULT error code:0x80020009
Exception occurred.
```

[Microsoft Support site](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/222758) says that the only required parameter is the filename.

Comment: Can you open older versions of powerpoint?  Notice that you are opening a .xls file in your first example, and a pptx (the new format) in your second...

Comment: Are you sure C:\file.pptx exists? I get that error if it doesn't.

Comment: @Marc Talbot, I also converted the file to ppt just in case. Both versions of the file are opened without a problem the manual way

Comment: @Anodyne, yes, thank you, I double checked just now.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006923/automating-office-via-windows-service-on-server-2008/1680214#1680214

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an ugly workaround:

```
  require 'win32ole'
  require 'fileutils'

  ppt = WIN32OLE.new('PowerPoint.Application')
  ppt.visible = true
  system "start c:/presentation.ppt"
  puts ppt.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count()
  ppt.ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Export("filename.jpg", ".jpg", 1024,768)
  ppt.ActivePresentation.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

I put a 3 second wait and it fixes the problem

Answer (score 0):

I got same error and adding `ppt.visible = true` was good enough for me.

Answer (score -1):

Try using Add instead of Open or Connect

for example:

`presentation = ppt.Presentations.Add('c:\file.pptx');`