# Opening a powerpoint presentation through a service fails

Tags: python, service, com, powerpoint

We are trying to create a set of services, some of which use powerpoint. Since we code the software in python, the services use the COM API to connect to powerpoint. The basic code is the following:

```
mutex = win32event.CreateMutex(None, False, 'mutexuniqueid')
if mutex is None:
    raise Exception('Mutex could not be created: %d' % (win32api.GetLastError()))
win32event.WaitForSingleObject(mutex, win32event.INFINITE)
try:
    pythoncom.CoInitializeEx(pythoncom.COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED)
    try:
        powerpoint = win32com.client.DispatchEx('Powerpoint.Application')
        presentation = powerpoint.Presentations.Open(r'Path\To\Cached\Presentation.ppt', False, True, False)
        # Do whatever necesary with the presentation
        presentation.Close()
        del presentation
finally:
    win32api.CloseHandle(mutex)
```

If we run the program, which is basically an rpc server, from the command prompt everything works without a problem, but if we install the program as a service, it fails during the `powerpoint.Presentations.Open` call with error:

```
(-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'Microsoft PowerPoint 2010', u'PowerPoint could not open the file.', u'', 0, -2147467259), None)
```

We have trace the problem and all the COM queries are executed correctly, we have the `Open` function there, so it really fails during the execution of it inside powerpoint.

There is the catch, we have tried in at least 10 computers, and it shows the same problem in each of them, except in one (which happens to be mine). We have check what are the difference between those machines and my own, but so far there's nothing.

**Update**
After checking different computers, we are managing the hypothesis that the problem is related to the session 0 isolation (services run in the session 0). The processes which break also do not appear to have a *Logon Session* while the machine which do work do show some *Logon Session* even though they also run in session 0.

Comment: Maybe a security issue. Does that work with a local file and LocalSystem as service identity?

Comment: It doesn't matter as which user is the service running, it's always the same

Answer (score 1):

So, it seems this problem happened before, and the solution is not why I had expected. The full answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006923/automating-office-via-windows-service-on-server-2008/1680214#1680214) but basically, you just need to be sure these folders exists:

```
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop
```

and

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop
```

Permisions for reading and writing are also needed.