# Cant open excel application from a powershell script when called from a jsp file under windows server 2008

Tags: java, excel, jsp, powershell, windows-server-2008

I have the following powershell script to open excel file and use excel save as PDF feature to generate a PDF file, and it works like a charm.

D:\test.ps1

```
$xlFixedFormat = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.xlFixedFormatType" -as [type] 
$xlRAMF = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlRunAutoMacro" -as [type] 
$xl = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
# Show Excel
$xl.visible = $true
$xl.DisplayAlerts = $False
# Create a workbook
$wb = $xl.Workbooks.open("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\CAP\Book1.xlsx") 
$wb.RunAutoMacros($xlRAMF::xlAutoActivate)
$wb.Saved = $true

$wb.ExportAsFixedFormat($xlFixedFormat::xlTypePDF, "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\CAP\Book1.pdf")
$xl.Workbooks.close() 
$xl.Quit()
```

And then we wrote this test JSP script to call that powershell script.

```
<%@page import="org.apache.cactus.server.*" session="true" %>
<%
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = runtime.exec("powershell D:\\test.ps1");
        java.io.InputStream is = proc.getInputStream();
        java.io.InputStreamReader isr = new java.io.InputStreamReader(is);
        java.io.BufferedReader reader = new java.io.BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            out.println(line);
        }
        reader.close();
        proc.getOutputStream().close();
%>
```

When running this JSP script  the Excel application is started under  local administrator, which is right because I already configured tomcat to run as a service using local administrator, but it never generates the PDF file nor the excel application is closed, could it be a security issue ?, for example do I need to change catalena security policy file ?, etc.
I already did the steps found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006923/automating-office-via-windows-service-on-server-2008)

Comment: Is there anything in the question that is unclear in anyway ?

Comment: Assuming that this is possible I wonder if there is just initial configuration that needs to be done. Have you run Excel while logged in as said administrator? In case Office has some things to set in the registry like owner information or something.

Comment: @matt yes I have, without any problems.